# C++ program runs slow in VS2008

Tags: c++, windows, linux, performance, visual-c++

I have a program written in C++, that opens a binary file(test.bin), reads it object by object, and puts each object into a new file (it opens the new file, writes into it(append), and closes it).
I use fopen/fclose, fread and fwrite.
test.bin contains 20,000 objects.

This program runs under linux with g++ in 1 sec but in VS2008 in debug/release mode in 1min!

There are reasons why I don't do them in batches or don't keep them in memory or any other kind of optimizations.

I just wonder why it is that much slow under windows.

Thanks,

Comment: What does your profiler tell you?

Comment: Duplicate (same user): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831039/visual-studio-2008-awful-performance

Comment: Might be the debug new and free code checking...  but you can profile it.  What happens under release?

Comment: 1. are you actually running the program in VS2008 or just compiling it? 2. do you have write-caching enabled for your hard drive in Windows? 3. what are the Linux numbers if you use fsync to force the files to be flushed to the hard drive?

Comment: Because you did something wrong.

Comment: What is the profiler that everybody talks about? Sorry, I am somehow new to VS.
Results for debug/release mode are nearly the same.
I'm using VS2008 IDE.
how can I turn write-caching on/off?
@John: What do you mean by wrong? be precise plz.

Comment: This kind of thing is soooo system dependent.  I saved minutes of time by copying my 2GB data file from network to my local PC before feeding it to my program.  In summary, you can't control how the OS processes your file requests when you use generic file operations.  (It could be waiting so it can make combine many small file I/O operations into one large one.)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your idea. Can you explain it more clearly?
I understand that it is highly platform dependent.

Comment: Can you post some part of the code ?

Comment: What do you mean debug/release mode?  It takes the same amount of time regardless of whether you try the debug build or the release build?

Comment: @Jagannath: unfortunately it is a bit huge! :D
@Adrian: yes, because the bottleneck is hard disk operations which seems to be irrelevant to debug/release mode.

Comment: @Nima:  I was only as precise as you were.  If you want a better answer to why your code is slow under Windows, we need to see your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately file access on Windows isn't renowned for its brilliant speed, particularly if you're opening lots of files and only reading and writing small amounts of data. For better results, the (not particularly helpful) solution would be to read large amounts of data from a small number of files. (Or switch to Linux entirely for this program?!)

Other random suggestions to try:

- turn off the virus checker if you have one (I've got Kaspersky on my PC, and writing 20,000 files quickly drove it bananas)
- use an NTFS disk if you have one (FAT32 will be even worse)
- make sure you're not accidentally using text mode with `fopen` (easily done)
- use `setvbuf` to increase the buffer size for each `FILE`
- try `CreateFile`/`ReadFile`/etc. instead of `fopen` and friends, which won't solve your problem but may shave a few seconds off the running time (since the stdio functions do a bit of extra work that you probably don't need)

Comment: It was McAfee Antivirus!! everytime it was trying to scan the file :))
Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

I believe that when you close a file in Windows, it flushes the contents to disk each time.  In Linux, I [don't think that is the case](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close).  The flush on each operation would be very expensive.

Comment: @Nima:  Even before you asked this, I had looked for information on how to accomplish that.  I was not able to find any obvious mechanism to mimic that behavior.

Comment: thanks :)
yes, neither could I. I think the best thing to do is to write a wrapper for a file, and implement the caching policies implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not matter of VS 2008. It is matter of Linux and Windows file system differences. And how C++ works with files in both systems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a lot of guessing here.

You're running under VS2008 IDE. You can always use the "poor man's profiler" and find out *exactly* what's going on.

In that minute, hit the "pause" button and look at what it's doing, including the call stack. Do this several times. Every single pause is almost certain (Prob = 59/60) to catch it doing precisely what it doesn't do under Linux.